# Can I load a WFS in a deegree Processlet?

Tags: wfs, wps, deegree

I am very new to deegree and Processlets.

After working through the [documentation](https://download.deegree.org/documentation/current/html/#_more_complex_configuration_example_5) and implementing both examples I am stuck. I cant find further examples or documentation on the possibilities of Processlets.

More concrete - is it possible to provide a Processlet with the id of a WFS as an input, perform calculations on the feature attributes is return a list of `feature results?

I am also very happy with further resources or examples.

EDIT: I did go through further [examples](https://github.com/deegree/deegree3/tree/master/deegree-workspaces/deegree-workspace-wps/src/main/java/org/deegree/wps/jts) and could not find an example of requesting features from an existing WFS.